# What type of backer board do I need to use to attach a stone veneer around a fireplace?

Tags: walls, fireplace, stone

I want to put up a stone veneer surround, around a gas fireplace we're going to install.  I've seen everything from using 1/2" plywood and a metal lath, to putting the tiles directly on drywall.  I have everything apart so I want to do this the best way.

The tiles/stones I will be using are quite heavy as they are real stone and not "manufactured stone".

Items in play:
 - Weight - heavier tiles
 - heat - over and around a fireplace
 - Indoor

Answer (score 5):

Drywall is out of the question due to weight, plywood might not give you the proper adhesion.

I would start with cement board, then attach the metal lath to that.  After the metal lath is secure, you'll have to apply a scratch coat of a sand and cement mix before applying the stone.

Here is a good guide for [applying stone veneer](http://www.themoldstore.info/Installing_Stone.html).

Comment: definitely start with a concrete board backer, avoid plywood in areas that may have heat issues, two reasons, fire danger and excessive expansion or contraction due to wide ranges of temp.

Comment: Good point shirlock, I overlooked that he was installing it near a fireplace.

Comment: No problem tester, you are usually right on.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using real Stone,  one thing to consider,  the wall doesn't support the weight , it just hold it from moving horizontally, any real Stone need a firm base to sit on like a heart or Concrete slab like your floor . This is called vertical load. The only attachment you need on the wall is a wall tie and a 8 penny nail. There should always be a hollow cavity behind the stone when laying. The wall tie is the mechanical anchor that transfers to the wood stud framing or shear wall. Fake Stone or stucco Stone is a totally different application, where cement board or lath is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

If you use cement board, you'll want to use a polymer modified mortar or thinset for the installation. If you use plywood, you'll need to install a weather resistant barrier, metal lath and put up a scratch coat. They both have there pros and cons, but I would probably recommend cement board. Make sure its actually cement board and not a composite board like hardybacker. Unfortunately stone veneer tends to sheet off on composite board unless it's installed with a very good bonding mortar or thinset.